# How far can i go just with this starter kit?

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to buy this kit: http://www.banggood.com/UNO-Basic-Starter-Learning-Kit-Upgrade-Version-For-Arduino-p-970714.html

However, as shipping stuff from China takes like 3 months to arrive, i need to be certain i won't have much else to buy.

How far can i go just with this kit, and what would you recommend me buying together with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as your imagination can take you. That's a decently comprehensive kit.

Comment: Without knowing your goals, that is unanswerable.  I'd be quite tempted to get a few basics like the board itself from a faster supplier, and then when this arrives you will have a second.  Are you looking at such slow sources dues to cost, or because all sources are slow to ship to wherever you are?

Comment: Yeah that is a massive starter kit so for beginning and learning it will be great. You have the basics there that will open up a much larger world. I did a laser spirograph and laser night light for my kids but those parts I could not source from an Arduino supplier. So depends on your projects and ideas.

Comment: That kit is quite good and/but, if you are prepared to source some of the basics in addition, I'd recommend at least considering something like [this kit](http://www.banggood.com/37-In-1-Sensor-Module-Board-Set-Kit-For-Arduino-p-89734.html) . I've NOT bought this but always thought this looked like a superb idea for experimenting. | I find [**these people**](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/213957/search?SearchText=arduino&origin=y) low cost & prompt and I have found their products good. Worth a look. I have no involvement except as a customer

Comment: I bought a basic original starter kit from Arduino comes with book. Gave it to my son 9 years and me both working and learning. Its very good to understand the basics and complete all chapters. If your foundation is solid then you would be able to go higher projects. Try to combine different projects and after short period of time you will be able to work on advanced projects using Arduino forums and other tons of information in net.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon. About half of the sensors are already present in the kit Igor was asking about. Though without the nice breakout board and headers. Other than that, a nice suggestion.

Comment: To answer some of your questions, shipping from China is the best option because anywhere outside Brazil takes ~3 months to arrive, and buying here is like 10x more expensive.
I do not have any experience with electronics overall, but i can read some books about it and tutorials and stuff. Basically, i'm willing to learn, haha.